# tkinter get values from dynamic checkboxes

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I am trying to create a number of dynamic checkboxes from data in a XML file.

I have no problems creating the button themselves, but I cant get the values generated by them.

Here is what I got so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = Tk()

def Readstatus():
    print(var.get())

listTree = ET.parse('list.xml')
listRoot = listTree.getroot()

var = dict()
count=1
for child in listRoot:
    var[child]=IntVar()
    chk = Checkbutton(root, text='Text'+str(count), variable=var[child], command=Readstatus)
    count += 1
    chk.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Gilles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event handler will return a TypeError as it expects 1 argument and got nothing. To make this a bit simpler, I modified the code so that it the key to the event handler.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = Tk()

def Readstatus(key):
    print(var.get(key))

listTree = ET.parse('test.xml')
listRoot = listTree.getroot()

var = dict()
count=1
for child in listRoot:
    var[child]=IntVar()
    chk = Checkbutton(root, text='Text'+str(count), variable=var[child], 
                      command=lambda key=child: Readstatus(key))
    count += 1
    chk.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This worked for me. I do think using Element objects for keys in the dictionary is a bit hard to debug, but I'm sure you have a good reason for doing that.

**EDIT**

To get just a 1 or 0 returned, change the event handler to look like this:

```
def Readstatus(key):
    var_obj = var.get(key)
    print(var_obj.get())
```

The **var.get()** command is actually calling a dictionary object's **get()** method, which is why it requires a key passed to it. Once you have the IntVar object returned, you can call its own **get** method to return the 0 or 1. See also:

- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and at this point, I am just happy when things work! :)

I see what You mean by using a dictionary, the only thing I get when click the boxes, are the default python variables names, and not the booleans you normally get with checkboxes, not very usefull, but in the right direction! :)

Any suggestions on how I could modify this to get say 0 on off, and 1 on on?

Again, thanks for your time, much appreciated!

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to get information from the returned IntVar object.

Comment: is there is any way to get the selected value instead of getting the key @MikeDriscoll